# Где находится логика предварительной обработки сущности при добавлении ее в репозиторий (БД)?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, проектирование, asp.net-web-api, solid

### UML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Код

```
class Particip
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}
interface IParticipRepository
{
    Particip Get(string code);
    Add(Particip item);
}

class ParticipRepository : IParticipRepository
{
    private dbContext db = new dbContext();
    public Add(Particip item)
    {
        db.Particips.Add(item);
    }

    public Particip Get(string code)
    {
        //...
    }
}

class ParticipCreator
{
    private IParticipRepository participRepository;
    public ParticipCreator(IParticipRepository participRepository)
    {
        this.participRepository = participRepository;
    }
    public Particip FactoryMethod(Particip unfinishedItem, string userLogin)
    {          
        var newCode = //...
        //алгоритм формирования кода для юзера
        //...
        unfinishedItem.Code = newCode;
        participRepository.Add(unfinishedItem);
        return unfinishedItem;
    }
}

class ParticipApiControlle : ApiController
{
    private IParticipRepository participRepository;
    private ParticipCreator participCreator;
    public ParticipApiControlle(IParticipRepository participRepository)
    {
        this.participRepository = participRepository;
        this.participCreator = new ParticipCreator(participRepository);
    }
    public Particip PostParticip(Particip unfinishedItem, string userLogin)
    {
        var item = participCreator.FactoryMethod(unfinishedItem, userLogin);
        return item;
    }

    public Particip Get(string code)
    {
        return participRepository.Get(code);
    }

}
```

---

### Пояснение

1. Пользователь заполняет форму, указывая реквизиты участника
   тестирования (`Particip`) - фамилия, имя и отчество;
2. После нажатия «Добавить», `AngularJS` передает Api-методу частично
   (не указано свойство Code) созданный объект `Particip` и логин
   (`User.Identity.Name`);
3. Теперь необходимо для свойства Code объекта Particip сформировать значение и только после этого добавить в БД.

Дело в том, что код для нового `участника-сущности БД` формируется особым образом и **зависит от текущего пользователя-логина**.

---

### Вопрос

**Где именно, согласно хорошему стилю проектирования, должна реализовываться логика формирования нового кода? Т.е. где лучше всего делать предобработку сущности при передачи ее репозиторию?**

Куда не посмотри, то везде рекомендуют делать Api и репозитории тонкими и я как видите, реализовал для этого паттерн «Фабричный метод» и в этом методе, получив объект `Particip` и логин (`userLogin`), формирую новый код и затем вызывая метод Add репозитория, добавляю в БД. *Быть может даже у меня не плохо получилось :)*

---

*Также у меня есть просьба: обратить внимание на мою UML-диаграмму - правильно ли я ее построил?*

Comment: Эта "логика предварительной обработки" обычно называется бизнес-логикой, и ее принято помещать в слой между контроллером и слоем доступа к данным (который у вас оформлен в виде репозиториев). Дергать репозитории напрямую из контроллеров допустимо только в мелких проектах или в мини-примерах, где бизнес логики нет.

Comment: @PashaPash, т.е. у меня не все так плохо выходит, так? Ведь мой класс `ParticipCreator` как-раз и находится между двумя этими товарищами.

Comment: да, примерно так